# Reconfigure the display-manager non-interactively

Tags: 18.04, lightdm, gdm, display-manager

I am trying to change the default display-manager on a Ubuntu 18.04.1 in a non-interactive way to do this in a script.

Everything works as expected when using

- `dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`
- `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

I tried setting `shared/default-x-display-manager` to a valid display-manager and run `dpkg-reconfigure`, but that did not do the trick.

---

First check which display-manager is set.

```
root@host:~# cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager
/usr/sbin/gdm3
root@host:~# cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager
/usr/sbin/gdm3
```

---

Then set `shared/default-x-display-manager` to `lightdm` and validate it.

```
root@host:~# echo set shared/default-x-display-manager lightdm | debconf-communicate 
0 value set
root@host:~# echo get shared/default-x-display-manager | debconf-communicate 
0 lightdm
```

---

Finally run `dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive lightdm` and check which display-manager is active. Which unfortunately is `gdm3` again.

```
root@host:~# dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive lightdm
root@host:~# echo get shared/default-x-display-manager | debconf-communicate 
0 gdm3
root@host:~# cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager 
/usr/sbin/gdm3
root@host:~# ll /etc/systemd/system/display-manager.service
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Jan 31 20:03 /etc/systemd/system/display-manager.service -> /lib/systemd/system/gdm3.service
```

---

The same happens if I want to switch from `lightdm` to `gdm3`.
Anything I am missing here or is this not intended to work at all?

I have seen in the scripts for `gdm3` that if there is a */etc/X11/default-display-manager.debconf-update* file, the `systemd` unit  and the */etc/X11/default-display-manager* are updated accordingly.
Unfortunately this does not work for `lightdm` as this one uses some other method(s) to do the work.

Hope someone else can shed some light on this and knows a convenient way to configure the display-manager non-interactively.

Answer (score 6):

After reading up the `.post*`, '.pre*' and `.config` scripts of `gdm3` and `lightdm` I have found a way to run `dpkg-reconfigure` interactively to change between the display managers and keep the magic of the mentioned `pre`, `post` and `config` scripts.

All you have to do is to update the */etc/X11/default-display-manager* file with the display manager binary you want to change to. Then run `dpkg-reconfigure` non-interactively and you are done. Well, `gdm3` does not update the `debconf` database, whereas `lightdm` does, but that is OK to do that manually.

Here we go...

---

Change from `lightdm` to `gdm3`.

```
$ echo "/usr/sbin/gdm3" > /etc/X11/default-display-manager
$ DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
$ echo set shared/default-x-display-manager gdm3 | debconf-communicate
```

---

Change from `gdm3` to `lightdm`.

```
$ echo "/usr/sbin/lightdm" > /etc/X11/default-display-manager
$ DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
$ echo set shared/default-x-display-manager lightdm | debconf-communicate
```

As already mentioned the last step `echo set shared/default-x-display-manager lightdm | debconf-communicate` is not really necessary here as the scripts of `lightdm` will take care of it. But for the sake of a simplified script it does not hurt to set it.

---

Putting things together into a shell script could be as follows. One could add more control if needed.

```
$ cat set_dm.sh
#!/bin/bash

set_dm() {
    DISPLAY_MANAGER="gdm3"
    DISPLAY_MANAGER_SERVICE="/etc/systemd/system/display-manager.service"
    DEFAULT_DISPLAY_MANAGER_FILE="/etc/X11/default-display-manager"

    if [ -n "${1}" ]
    then
        DISPLAY_MANAGER="$1"
    fi

    DISPLAY_MANAGER_BIN="/usr/sbin/${DISPLAY_MANAGER}"
    if [ ! -e "${DISPLAY_MANAGER_BIN}" ]
    then
        echo "${DISPLAY_MANAGER} seems not to be a valid display manager or is not installed."
    exit 1
    fi

    echo "${DISPLAY_MANAGER_BIN}" > "${DEFAULT_DISPLAY_MANAGER_FILE}"
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true dpkg-reconfigure "${DISPLAY_MANAGER}"
    echo set shared/default-x-display-manager "${DISPLAY_MANAGER}" | debconf-communicate &> /dev/null 

    echo -n "systemd service is set to: "
    readlink "${DISPLAY_MANAGER_SERVICE}" 

    echo -n "${DEFAULT_DISPLAY_MANAGER_FILE} is set to: "
    cat "${DEFAULT_DISPLAY_MANAGER_FILE}"

    echo -n "debconf is set to: "
    echo get shared/default-x-display-manager | debconf-communicate 
}

set_dm $1
```

---

The two variables `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` and  `DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true` are needed to really run interactively.

What also helped was the environment variable `DEBCONF_DEBUG` to see what `debconf` is doing. It can be set to

- `user`
- `developer`
- `db`
- `.*` which is all of the above

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  This was the only thing I could find which actually showed how to do this non-interactively *and worked* so that I could update a large number of Ubuntu hosts automatically (via Puppet) to switch them from lightdm to gdm  :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an ansible recipe for doing this on Ubuntu 20 for people using that tool.

```
---

- name: Render /etc/X11/default-display-manager
  template:
    src: etc/X11/default-display-manager
    dest: /etc/X11/default-display-manager
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: "0644"
  become: yes

- name: Switch to XFCE4 window manager
  debconf:
    name: lightdm
    question: shared/default-x-display-manager
    vtype: string
    value: lightdm
  register: reconfigure_xfce4
  become: yes

- name: Reconfigure dpkg with XFCE4 choice
  command: dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
  environment:
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND: noninteractive
    DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN: true
  become: yes
  when: reconfigure_xfce4.changed

- name: Select XFCE4 as session manager
  command: update-alternatives --set x-session-manager /usr/bin/xfce4-session
  become: yes
  when: reconfigure_xfce4.changed

- name: Set runlevel default to multi-user
  file:
    src: /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target
    dest: /etc/systemd/system/default.target
    state: link
  become: yes
  register: change_runlevel

- name: Set runlevel to multi-user
  command: systemctl isolate multi-user.target
  become: yes
  when: change_runlevel.changed
```